# Stanford NNDep parser: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

After training a model, i’m trying to parse the test treebank. Unfortunately, this error keeps popping up:

```
Loading depparse model file: nndep.model.txt.gz ...
###################
#Transitions: 77
#Labels: 38
ROOTLABEL: root
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.Classifier.preCompute(Classifier.java:663)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.Classifier.preCompute(Classifier.java:637)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.initialize(DependencyParser.java:1151)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.loadModelFile(DependencyParser.java:589)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.loadModelFile(DependencyParser.java:493)
        at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser.main(DependencyParser.java:1245)
```

If the pre-trained english model, which ships with the NLP package, is used, that error does not appear. Therefore, there is maybe something wrong with the trained model? There were no errors during training, however. 500 iterations were done (default 20000 takes over 15 hours on my 2,33 GHz Core 2 Duo CPU @ 4 Gb RAM – is such an amount of time normal, by the way?)　Train, dev and test sets are [UD 1.2](http://lindat.mff.cuni.cz/repository/xmlui/handle/11234/1-1548); word embeddings used are [these](http://github.com/wolet/sprml13-word-embeddings). Seems that this error happens when non-english treebank is used for training (tried swedish and polish UD; `-tlp` option is not set, using `UniversalEnglish`).

Comment: Are you certain that you are running with the same `embeddingSize` and `hiddenSize` flags as you did when training?

Comment: FYI, yes, we know the CPU version is slow to train. We used an internal GPU implementation to train the released models. Unfortunately we don't plan to maintain a public GPU-enabled CoreNLP at the moment, and so we can't include it as part of our public API.

Comment: I was folllowing the guide at nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml, with the pipe looking as java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -model modelOutputFile.txt.gz -testFile TextToParse -outFile dependenciesOutputFile.txt. So as i understood, the flags you mention are for training only, not for parsing (?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question, with a hint in a comment by [@Jon Gauthier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726828/stanford-nndep-parser-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception#comment55226423_33726828). It turns out that the `-embeddingSize` flag is needed *also at parsing stage* if it was used during training (= other value then the default 50 was used). The [documentation](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml) never says that, and in fact only refers to the flag in regards to the training phase, but the error message in the question code actually cryptically hints about the origin of the error, displaying „25“̦ which was the dimensionality of the word embeddings used.

Comment: I have the same problem , do you also set the hiddenSize flag in test? and would you please write here one line in your embeddingFile , so that I know I am using the write embeddingFile?

Comment: Nope, i only used the `-embeddingSize` flag. The embeddings i use are linked in the OP and can be freely downloaded.