# CoreNLP Neural Network Dependency Parser - Difference between evaluation during training versus testing

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am trying to train a new model with the Stanford CoreNLP implementation of the neural network parser of Chen and Manning (2014). During training, I use the `-devFile` option to do a UAS evaluation on the development set every 100 iterations. After a few thousand iterations I get a fairly good UAS (around 86 per cent). However, after the training is completed and I try to test it on the same development set, I get a UAS of around 15 per cent. I am using the English Universal Dependencies treebank.

Command line options for training:

```
java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -trainFile ~/Datasets/universal-dependencies-1.2/UD_English/en-ud-train.conllu -devFile ~/Datasets/universal-dependencies-1.2/UD_English/en-ud-dev.conllu -embedFile path/to/wordvecs -embeddingSize 100 -model nndep.model.txt.gz  -trainingThreads 2
```

Command line options for testing:

```
java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -model nndep.model.txt.gz -testFile ~/Datasets/universal-dependencies-1.2/UD_English/en-ud-dev.conllu
```

When I use the provided UD model for English everything works fine, and I get a UAS of around 80 per cent on the development set. This leads me to believe that my trained model is subpar, and that I might have missed some needed step or option. But since the evaluation during training gives pretty good results, I am a bit confused. From my understanding there should not be that big of a difference between these two evaluations.

So, what might be the cause of the large discrepancy between the evaluation during training versus that at testing time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.
I found the answer to this problem in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33788775/6082557), although their problem was a bit different.

When you use an embedding size that is different from the default value of 50, you need to pass the -embeddingSize flag when parsing as well. As noted in the above linked thread, this goes for the hidden size parameter as well.

Doing this resolved the problem, and I get a UAS that is equivalent to the one during training.

So, if you use an word embedding or hidden layer size that is different from the default value, you need to pass those parameters when parsing with the model.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error, I don't know if it was for copy-paste, but in:

"Command line options for testing:"

```
java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -model nndep.model.txt.gz -testFile ~/Datasets/universal-dependencies-1.2/UD_English/en-ud-**dev**.conllu
```

I think it should be:

```
java edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -model nndep.model.txt.gz -testFile ~/Datasets/universal-dependencies-1.2/UD_English/en-ud-**test**.conllu
```